# Vagrant ssh using -c or --COMMAND causes the session to close

Tags: ruby, linux, ssh, virtual-machine, vagrant

I have an issue with vagrant executing commands over ssh. The session terminates after acknowledging my command.

For example if I type

```
vagrant ssh -c "echo hello"
```

hello will appear in the terminal and then the session closes.

Other than config.ssh.timeout is there any other setting I should check or change?

Answer (score 1):

That's the expected behavior. Just like in normal `ssh <command>`, the command is run and session closed after the commend exits. This is also [documented](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/cli/ssh.html).

Comment: Yes thats true (bad example) but it still ends the session early even if I tell it to execute a process. For a test, I assigned a private IP to vagrant and ssh a command to it. It executed the process until it finished which is the correct behavior I was expecting. However when using the same command via vagrant ssh, it terminated early. Not sure whats causing this. DO not see anything in the log files.

Comment: What do you mean by "execute a process"? Does it fork/detach? Maybe the normal ssh connection stays open if the process doesn't close stdin. `vagrant ssh` might well close stdin itself so maybe there's the difference.